# How to subtract from two different tables in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

When I click the button, it got no error but the database have not change anything

```
protected void btnBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        string id = Session["UserID"].ToString();
       
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProducts SET PQuantity=t1.PQuantity-t2.Quantity FROM tblOrderProducts t2 INNER JOIN tblProducts t1 ON t2.OrderProID=t1.PID";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       
        Response.Redirect("OrderConfirmation.aspx");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Query:

```sql
UPDATE tblProducts
SET PQuantity = (t1.PQuantity - t2.Quantity)
FROM tblOrderProducts t2
INNER JOIN tblProducts t1 ON t2.OrderProID = t1.PID
```

Comment: At what point do you create your order (i.e. actually add a record to `tblOrderProducts `). I would expect the order of execution to be 1. Create your Order (guessing in `tblOrders`) 2. Add your order products 3. Update your quantities using only the records you have just created.

Comment: With that being said, managing your quantities in this way is not the way I would approach it. If you keep track of your purchases and your sales, then your current inventory (or inventory at any given date in the past) can be calculated based on these two tables, and you don't need to worry about maintaining a quantity column against your products.

Comment: If you're still in the design phase for your database too, I'd really recommend not using the `tbl` prefix. While it is subjective and your choice, the general consensus is that it adds nothing but unnecessary noise to your SQL - [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem)

Comment: Start over - and pay attention to all the suggestions and comments made to your previous questions. You just are NOT learning good habits and are NOT thinking about your code. Here your code implies that the user is working with a cart (or at least a particular item). Your code should be first creating an order for the purchase and then deducting the appropriate amount from your inventory for **that product**. Your code updates EVERY PRODUCT from every order. You were at least using the correct approach in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET PQuantity = (t1.PQuantity - t2.Quantity)
FROM tblProducts AS t1, tblOrderProducts AS t2
WHERE t2.OrderProID = t1.PID
```

Comment: Using old-style joins is discouraged by everyone

Answer (score -1):

I think use subquery is good for you

```
UPDATE 
 SET PQuantity = (select PQuantity FROM tblProducts Where PID =t2.OrderProID ) - t2.Quantity)
FROM tblOrderProducts t2
```